# How to filter out items in array of objects based on item in property array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to return items in an array of object if they contain a certain property in a property which is an array?

I have the following array of objects:

```
const menus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'English',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Spanish',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_SP']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'German',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_DE']
  },  
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'German and english',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN', 'MENU_DE']
  },
]
```

As an example, I am looking for a way to return any items which have 'MENU_EN' in the locations property. So I need a function which will return the following:

```
const filteredMenus = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'English',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN']
  },  
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'German and english',
    locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN', 'MENU_DE']
  },
]
```

Comment: There are many different ways to achieve this. Please add the code _you've_ attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: [Filtering array of objects based on properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes), [Checking if an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter `menus` array using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by checking if locations property includes the desired `MENU_EN` with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

Code:

```js
const menus = [{id: 1,title: 'English',locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN']},{id: 2,title: 'Spanish',locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_SP']},{id: 3,title: 'German',locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_DE']},{id: 4,title: 'German and english',locations: ['MENU', 'MENU_EN', 'MENU_DE']},]

const filteredMenus = menus.filter(({ locations }) => locations.includes('MENU_EN'))

console.log(filteredMenus)
```

Comment: Please add links to MDN documentation for `filter` and `includes`. Maybe explain what it is you've done. "Try this" or "you can do" is rarely useful.

Comment: @Andy improved answer. Thank you for your comment