# Typescript filter give me array of values that don't meet condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Very new to typescript, using the filter function on below array, I would expect filter.length to be 1 as we have one person with a role of Principal. but I receive 2 as it is checking how many roles do not have that index, how can i check how many role arrays contain at least 1 value of Principal?

```js
const people = [
    {
        "roles": [
            "Claimant"
        ],
        "name": "mick"
    },
    {
        "roles": [
            "Principal"
        ],
        "name": "paddy"
    },
    {
        "roles": [
            "Claimant"
        ],
        "name": "bob"
    }
]

            const filter = people.filter((obj)=> obj.roles.indexOf('Principal') )
            console.log(filter.length)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter out items in array of objects based on item in property array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72109838/how-to-filter-out-items-in-array-of-objects-based-on-item-in-property-array-in-j)

Comment: and its duplicates: [How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes) and [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array#includes` instead, which returns a boolean indicating if the element was present.

`Array#indexOf` returns the index of the element. The first element would be index `0`, which is falsy, so `filter` does not keep the element.

```js
const people=[{roles:["Claimant"],name:"mick"},{roles:["Principal"],name:"paddy"},{roles:["Claimant"],name:"bob"}];
const filter = people.filter((obj)=> obj.roles.includes('Principal'))
console.log(filter.length);
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore case when doing this check?

Comment: @AnonymousAlias Replace the filter callback with `obj.roles.some(r => r.toLowerCase() === 'principal')`

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns -1 for a non-match, so you want to use `obj.roles.indexOf('Principal') > -1`